# How does the “有“ affect the meaning of a sentence beginning 有一天 vs. 一天?

Tags: grammar, meaning

How does the “有“ affect the meaning of sentence?

‎What is the difference between 有一天国王把他的故事给一名作家 and 一天国王把他的故事给一名作家.

Comment: see my answer to your other [post](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/51804/how-does-%e7%bb%99-change-verb-meaning/51805?noredirect=1#comment70576_51805)

Answer (score 1):

有一天 - "On one day".

一天 - "One day", or "A day".

Sometimes, there is no difference between the two, for example, the sentence below means the same with or without "有".

- "他從不提過去的遭遇. 但(有)一天心血來潮, 国王把他的故事告訴了一名作家...". Here, "有" makes the sentence more complete, but its presence is not absolutely necessary.

However, "有" can't be eliminated for the (predictive) sentences below:

- **有**一天等我長大了
- **有**一天我會告訴你

Comment: 有一天 - "On one day".  Maybe "On that day"?

Comment: @WayneCheah I think *There is one day" translated by TangHo on the OP's another post is better. Don't you feel "On that day" sounds like "那一天"?

Comment: "On one day" and *There is one day" sound awkward as English phrases. Anyway, on reflection, yes, "On that day" sounds like "那一天" It is difficult to translate precisely the nuances of 有一天 into a bite-size sensible English equivalent. Like "Once upon a time" has, usually, been translated as 曾几何时 which do not really capture the linguistic nuances of "Once upon a time". Another difficult phrase is "Time immemorial, or time whereof the memory of man runneth not to the contrary"

Comment: @WayneCheah Yes, the difference is rather difficult to explain with merely a few words.

Answer (score 0):

Both "一天" and "有一天" serve as an adverbial of time, and there is a note of "in the past" in both of them, so we actually don't distinguish them. As to the effect of "有", "有" is similiar to "there be" as @Tang Ho posted. So the two are like: "one day" & "there is one day". But I don't think "有一天" is equivalent to "there is one day", because of the "in the past" note, while "there is one day" may occur when we make assumptions of the future.