# How does 给 change the verb meaning in 有一天国王把他的故事给一名作家看?

Tags: grammar, verbs

In the sentence 有一天国王把他的故事给一名作家看 , the intended meaning is, “One day the king showed his stories to a writer”. 看 by itself means to see or to look at. 给 is used as “to” but does this change the meaning of 看 and if so how does the use of 给 change the meaning of verbs?

Comment: I feel it's inconsiderate to ask the same question on multiple forums like [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/vzroih/the_use_of_%E7%BB%99/) and [HiNative](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/22270293); it wastes people's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

给 (give)--> allow -->let.

- 有一天 - there's one day
- 国王 - the king
- 把他的故事 - take his story
- [**给**] - let
- 一名作家看 - a writer read (it)

> 有一天国王把他的故事[**给**]一名作家看 --> There's one day the king [**let**] a writer read his story

Comment: "有一天 - there's one day", I think this answered the OP's question on another thread.